# Application performance problem Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i am facing a big speed problem with my application..we have to go for production but it got push backed becoz of this speed issue..

In my application..i have a page which is the main and important page of whole application..
in this page user spend most of the time...
in this page i am using 6 to 7 javascript files and jquery plugins..
whole page is ajax based and will do the jquery validations...
in this page i have 3 update panels (nested)..one update panel contains one formview and
other will contain one grid and a 4 formviews(will make visible of user selection..4 of the won't come at time..depends on grid view item i will get visible..like grid view record is type one then type one formview will visible on the page)..one update panel is parent update panel..
each formview contains more than 10 controls..dropdowns will load on formview onload event from database loopup tables..
this page won't refresh at all..because ever thing is in update panels..
i can't set the view state to false because of update panels..
i have to make more than 5 database calls each time..

this page works fine at the beginning of application start..after some amount of time its getting slower and slower..the database calls are pretty fast at the beginning and getting very slow after some time...
i don't know how to debug this thing and how to find which one causes this problem....please help me...

Update:
my view state is growing from 35 kb to 160 kb..
and i tried fullpost back triggers for some controls in updatepanels.. but the view state not getting down..its stays like that..on a double or triple browser refresh it got back to 35 kb..is this the issue?? thanks for your replies and suggestions...

Comment: We can't really offer suggestions of what to correct if we don't see any code. Please post some of your code or more specific questions and we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a very long testing i found the problem...its because of update panels...we should not use update panel for too many controls..I didn't know that and the only control we have in asp.net is update panel for ajax..that's why i used the updatepanels...please stop using updatepanels and try to use jquery..i suffered a lot with this issue...thanks for your support guys...

Answer (score 0):

I can't really help you if you don't show your code (specifically, the code the runs the database queries that start to slow down), but I can make one (hopefully good) guess:

It sounds like you might not be disposing your database connections properly.  Every time you open a connection to the database, make sure you either wrap it in a try/finally block (where .Close() is called in the finally block) or create it with a `using` block.

Comment: i am doing exactly same thing..do you think its because of view state??right now my view state size at the start is 35 kb and it is growing to 160kb after some time..

Answer (score 0):

You should look into a tool like [JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/buy/index.jsp) that allows your monitor performance on a granular level.  Then you will be able to see what the actual cause of your poor performance is.  You get a 10 day trial at the website I linked to.